# css counter-reset: not working in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-counter

Has the Firefox desktop v84 update broken the CSS counter-reset: functionality?
Chrome and Edge render ok but not Firefox
Can anybody confirm?

Below is a sample of the code that I'm using:

```css
body
{
counter-reset: section subsection;
}
p.section
{
  counter-reset: subsection;
}
p.section:before
{
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "" counter(section) ".0" ": ";
  counter-reset: subsection;
}
p.subsection:before
{
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: "" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 1.0</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 2.0</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.1</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.2</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 3.0</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 4.0</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 4.1</p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the line in the `body` style be `counter-set`, not `counter-reset`? `counter-set` creates a counter if it doesn't already exist but `counter-reset` is only supposed to update existing counters.

Comment: Why v84 just released?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in [current W3C CSS specification draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists/#auto-numbering), `counter-reset` is expected to instantiate a new counter, whereas `counter-set` edits an existing counter (and creates a new one in case there is none with that name).

In your code:

- The properties `counter-reset: subsection;` create new counters called “subsection” in `body`, `p.section` and `p.section::before` scopes respectively.
- `p.subsection` inherits both counters from its parent (`body`).

  - Chromium wrongly inherits the `subsection` counter created by its preceding sibling (but not the one created by `::before` pseudo-element).
- Then, `p.subsection` counter values have to be updated from preceding element ones.

  - In Firefox ≥ 82, the original `subsection` counter has not been updated, since you create a new counter each time.
  - In Chromium, you have inherited the counter from preceding sibling, so its value can be updated and is actually used. But the `subsection` counter created at `body` level is useless.

To fix you code, complying with current specification and having a browser consistent behavior, you have two possibilities:

### Use `counter-set: subsection` rule

In order to edit the counter instead of creating a new one. Note `counter-set` [is not supported by Safari yet](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_counter-set).

```css
body
{
counter-reset: section subsection; /* subsection counter is “global” */
}
/*
* Useless rule, you already perform a reset in .section::before *
p.section
{
  counter-reset: subsection;
} */
p.section::before
{
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ".0: ";
  counter-set: subsection; /* Edits the body counter to set it to 0 */
}
p.subsection::before
{
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3>With counter-set</h3>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 1.0</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 2.0</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.1</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.2</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 3.0</p>
<p class="section">Paragraph should be 4.0</p>
<p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 4.1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

### Make `.subsection` children of `.section`

In order to properly inherit counters.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section; /* subsection counter is not “global” */
}
div.section::before
{
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ".0: ";
  counter-reset: subsection; /* Creates a new counter for each section. */
}
div.subsection::before
{
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3>Tree ordering</h3>
<div class="section">Should be 1.0</div>
<div class="section">Should be 2.0
  <div class="subsection">Should be 2.1</div>
  <div class="subsection">Should be 2.2</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Should be 3.0</div>
<div class="section">Should be 4.0
  <div class="subsection">Should be 4.1</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note there are still [discussions](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5477), so you should not expect `counter-reset` CSS feature to be stable.

Answer (score 1):

Ouroborus's comment on your question is the key: use `counter-set` on your `body` style to *create* the counters, and continue to use `counter-reset` on other elements to *reset* them. I had the same problem with Firefox, and switching to `counter-set` on the `body` style fixed it.

This seems to be a recent Firefox change: previously, the counters seemed to be implicitly created, and now it seems that creation has to be done explicitly.

Comment: Note this answer says *switch* `counter-reset` to `counter-set`.  I first tried with both  `counter-set` and `counter-reset` for fear of breaking in other browsers -- this did not work.  I had to remove `counter-reset` from the `body` to get things working properly.

Comment: You got it - it's the switch to `set` rather than `reset` that is the real fix here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. No need to reset the *subsection* in the `body`, because we need to reset the counter after every `section`. so we have kept the counter reset *subsection* in the `section` as it is.

Please refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/baqnzf39/6/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      counter-reset: section;
    }

    p.section {
      counter-reset: subsection;
    }

    p.section:before {
      counter-increment: section;
      content: ""counter(section) ".0"": ";
      counter-reset: subsection;
    }

    p.subsection:before {
      counter-increment: subsection;
      content: ""counter(section) "."counter(subsection) ": ";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="section">Paragraph should be 1.0</p>
  <p class="section">Paragraph should be 2.0</p>
  <p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.1</p>
  <p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 2.2</p>
  <p class="section">Paragraph should be 3.0</p>
  <p class="section">Paragraph should be 4.0</p>
  <p class="subsection">Paragraph should be 4.1</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use

`counter-set foo 0`

rather than

`counter-reset foo`

It seems Firefox's `counter-reset` has different semantics from Chrome. This works around their differences.